# Program not terminating before forking

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a simple C program, it basically asks for a file name to read or `\0` to terminate the program.

My problem is when I input `\0` it does not terminate, instead it keeps creating the fork and executing the other c program as child, any idea why?

```
int main (void)
{
    printf("%d: Parent process ...\n",getpid());
    char fileName[200];

    printf ("%d: Enter an argument (or \\0 for none): ", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%c", &fileName);

    if(fileName == "\\0"){
        exit(0);
    }

    int pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("%d child\n",getpid());
        execl ("./catter","catter", fileName,NULL);
    }
    sleep(6);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use end-of-stream as the way to signal that you don't want an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has at least two problems, the first is `%c` in `scanf()` is used for single `char`, not a string, you should use `%s` instead, or better, use `fgets()` for this job.

```
fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin);
```

The second is that you are using `==` to compare strings, `if(fileName == "\\0")` would NEVER be true. `strcmp()` is the function you are looking for:

```
if (strcmp(fileName, "\\0") == 0)
```